# Create a login form with TextInput in child component

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and I am trying to implement a simple Login form.

I tried the following first, which works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import TitledInput from './login-form';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { email: '', password: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          label='Email Adress'
          placeholder='you@domain.com'
          value={this.state.email}
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Then I wanted to split the input in another independent component called `TitledInput` and tried this (which is not working):

**LoginForm**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
    } from 'react-native';

    import TitledInput from './login-form';

    export default class LoginForm extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { email: '', password: ''};
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TitledInput
              label='Email Adress'
              placeholder='you@domain.com'
              value={this.state.email}
              onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

**TitledInput**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class TitledInput extends Component {
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <Text style={label}>{props.label.toUpperCase()}</Text>
        <TextInput
          autoCorrect={false}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry}
          value={props.value}
          onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
          style={input}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I get a `'maximum call stack exceeded'` error.

I could read on the internet that this error can occur when calling `setState` in a `re-render` function... but I don't know how to handle this case where I want my login form to know the value a its input child component.

I want to know it because I will use it when clicking the submit button or is it the whole purpose of the state?

Answer (score 1):

while you are changing email input value in `TiledInput` email value will propagate to `LoginForm`. In LoginForm because of state "email" change the login form will rerender. In this case you have to use [ComponentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) inorder to get the new email value.

Instead of this approach you can have another state value inside TitledInput to keep email value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

import TitledInput from './login-form';

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { email: '', password: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TitledInput
          label='Email Adress'
          placeholder='you@domain.com'
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// TitledInput
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class TitledInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { text: ''};
    }
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;

  handleTextChange(value){
     this.setState({text:value});
     this.props.onChangeText(value);
  }
  render() {
        return (
          <View style={container}>
                <Text style={label}>{props.label.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                <TextInput
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  placeholder={props.placeholder}
                  secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry}
                  value={this.state.text}
                  onChangeText={this.handleTextChange()}
                  style={input}
                />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

[update] By using onBlur instead of onChangeText you can reduce the number of function call

Comment: It seems that your device cant handle much function calls. So intead of using onchangetext use onBlur

Comment: Refer this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14051 but still not solved